# Zabbix LLD Prometheus format metrics

Tags: parsing, prometheus, metrics, zabbix

I am trying to parse some Prometheus format metrics by Zabbix discovery rule.
I have metrics like that:

```
asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", tag="ASG_DESIRED_NUM"} 3
asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", tag="ASG_MAX_SIZE"} 10
asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", tag="ASG_MIN_SIZE"} 3
asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", tag="alpha.eksctl.io/nodegroup-type"} unmanaged
asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", tag="aws:ec2launchtemplate:id"} lt-***
```

I use "Prometheus to JSON" preprocessing for discovery rule.

In case of first three lines - it is parsing and converting to JSON without any problems, but next metrics can't be parsed, i am getting next error:

> cannot convert Prometheus data to JSON: data parsing error at row 4
> "asg_instance_metadata{id="i-***", ta...": cannot parse
> metric value

In these Zabbix docs

- [Link1](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/prometheus)
- [Link2](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/examples/prometheus)

I see examples only with INT values.

So can someone help me? Is it possible to use string values in prometheuse format metrics?

My discovery rule configuration:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Prometheus metrics values must be float64. The 4th metric is not a valid Prometheus metric value. See [data model](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/)

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for your answer.
I am not really good in prometheus.